# how to make a node http request pause execution until complete

Tags: node.js, http, sails.js

I'm getting a JSON response from a service that I want to pass on to another function.  When I put a breakpoint on the `var parsedData...` line and one on the `return resp`, the parsedData line gets hit first.  How can I "wait" for the request to finish before moving on in the code?

```
var data = sendRequest(options);
var parsedData = parseData(commits);

var sendRequest = function (options) {
    var resp = {}
    var request = https.request(options, function (response) {
        var body = '';
        response.on("data", function (chunk) {
            body += chunk.toString('utf8');
        });

        response.on("error", function(e){
            console.log(e);
        })

        response.on("end", function () {
            resp = JSON.parse(body);
            return resp;
        });
    });
    request.end();
}
```

Comment: why you don't call `parsedData = parseData(commits);` next to `resp = JSON.parse(body);` ?

Answer (score 0):

add a callback argument to `sendRequest`

```
var data = sendRequest(options, function(){
    var parsedData = parseData(commits);
});

var sendRequest = function (options, callback) {
    var resp = {}
    var request = https.request(options, function (response) {
        var body = '';
        response.on("data", function (chunk) {
            body += chunk.toString('utf8');
        });

        response.on("error", function(e){
            console.log(e);
        })

        response.on("end", function () {
            resp = JSON.parse(body);
            callback(resp);
        });
    });
    request.end();
}
```

Comment: how does this work when trying to modify existing objects? example:

`return{
a: sendRequest(a),
b: sendRequest(b)}`

(I'm getting undefined for the object)